# Installed PaintSupreme 3D and it is not loading

Tags: software-installation

Hello I have tried to install PaintSupreme 3D on to my Ubuntu 19.10 system. When I attempt to open the app via its icon nothing happens.

I have installed it via the software app, and then removed it, and then installed via terminal (no errors were displayed).

When I use the terminal to run it this is what is displayed:

```
~$ paintsupreme-3d
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

If I use sudo I get a little bit more information:

```
~$ sudo paintsupreme-3d
No schema files found: doing nothing.
/snap/paintsupreme-3d/2/bin/desktop-launch: line 204:  3565 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $RUNTIME/usr/lib/$ARCH/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > $GDK_PIXBUF_MODULE_FILE
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

I am at a complete loss to as why the app isn't working.

Comment: I can certainly duplicate your error messages with this application on 19.10. Digging around a little...

Answer (score 1):

I've launched it from midnight commander from /snap/paintsupreme-3d/2

And got new description of error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

then i've installed missing library:

```
sudo apt install libgconf2-4
```

Than paintsupreme-3d lauched!

P.S.

Also you must to edit link in main menu.

to open it, you must do this command:

```
/snap/paintsupreme-3d/2/paintsupreme-3d
```

P.P.S.
Sorry for my bad E.